# get mouse X,Y coords relative to a frame

Tags: java, events

I have a button and when I use mouse on the button I want to know the mouse x,y coords relative to the frame

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

`getBounds()` gives you a `Rectangle` with the position and dimensions of the button relative to its parent. In my example the parent is the `JFrame`.

```
public class Click { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final JFrame f = new JFrame("Click pos");
                f.setSize(640, 480);

                final JButton b = new JButton("Click Me!");
                b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        final JButton bb = (JButton) e.getSource();
                        final Rectangle bbox = bb.getBounds();
                        final int x = bbox.x + e.getX();
                        final int y = bbox.y + e.getY();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "pos: " + x + " " + y);
                    }
                });
                f.getContentPane().add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Edit:
With the helper methods from SwingUtilities the `mouseClicked` method gets much simpler. And you get the correct coordinates independent of how many containers are between the `JFrame` and the `JButton`. I wasn't aware of them.

```
                    final JButton bb = (JButton) e.getSource();
                    Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(bb, e.getPoint(), f);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, p);
```

Answer (score 0):

register a [MouseListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) and implement the corresponding events. MouseEvent has getX and getY methods that can give you the mouse position.

Comment: Yes but when I'm in the button the JFrame does not fire that event

Comment: Try this code inside the button's event listener:

    PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point b = a.getLocation();
    int x = (int) b.getX();
    int y = (int) b.getY();

Comment: No it give me the coords relative to the button not to the frame!

Comment: Checkout the SwingUtilities class. It has helper methods to convert MouseEvent co-ordinates and other utility methods for converting points relative to components and screen.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html